# How can I prevent Magento from changing permissions of my files after a Backup?

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

I have a big problem. Everytime I backup my magento store I have to re-set up the permissions for my folders and files. This consumes much time in which my store isn't **reachable**. Anyone got a solution for this? I only saw changing the permissions via FileZilla ect. but this is sooo time consuming. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I recomand you this [tool](https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php).
Put the file "magento-cleanup.php" in magento root folder and run the file in browser.
This file change permitions for all files and folders, clearing cache folder, session folder, minifycache folder, pearlib cache folder, pearlib download folder, pear.ini file.

Good luck with that

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a different in speed between this and changing permissions via filezilla?

Comment: [view this printscreen](https://goo.gl/wpBPHI) for FileZilla

Comment: @urson88en - It's ok printscreen? You did?